# Is there a CSS way to get a nav bottom border to align with the hover border?

Tags: html, css, width, border, nav

I've created a basic nav with the following structure:

```
<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Another Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Another Link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The nav is a typical horizontal one with `li`s floated to the left. The thing is, the nav is dynamic per user, and the nav will never take up 100% the width of the screen.
However, I want the hovered/current nav link to have a red underline, and the rest of the nav **across the remaining width of the site container** to have a different colored bottom border.
Here's an image of what I want:

[image: Bottom border example]

I can do this by attaching a background image of the default border color to the nav `div`, but I'm not sure how to do this with pure CSS.

Is this possible?
Thank you.

---

**Edit**: Here's the CSS (and please note that the CSS does not give me the intended effect):

```
.nav ul {
  border-bottom: #DDD solid 5px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
}

.nav a {
  border-bottom: #FFF solid 5px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav_link:hover {
  border-bottom: #F00 solid 5px;
  color: #F00;
}

.current_page {
  border-bottom: #F00 solid 5px;
  color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: Post the CSS you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible solution.

Set a top and bottom border on your `nav` element. Then with your `a` tags, set them with a bottom border matching the non-hover color and size. Set a negative `margin-bottom` on the `a` tag equal to the size of the `nav` `border-bottom`. And then change the border color of the `a` element on hover.

Here's a fiddle showing it: http://jsfiddle.net/FNLmf/

*Note: I did not use floats, I used `inline-block`. You can use floats, just be sure to clearfix your `nav` element.

Comment: Yes, that worked perfectly. As you recommended, I had to change the `li`s from floated left to `inline-block` in order to get rid of the `overflow: hidden;` for the sake of clearing the floats. Thanks again for the awesome answer.

Comment: Great. One thing to note with using `inline-block` is the whitespace issue between each block. You can easily find ways to handle that though so it looks as tight and clean as floats do. Enjoy!

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. I just added a left margin of -4px to all `li`s that weren't the first one. Thanks.

Comment: You should change `margin-bottom: -4px` to `-3.5px;` to align the elements properly.